# Oracle reports center aligning the header of a field in a repeating frame

Tags: oracle, layout, report, oraclereports

I have a label and a field as in the follwing layout.

```
________________
|  _____       |
| |     |      |
| |Label|      |
| |_____|      |
|              |
| ____________ |->Outer fixedframe  
| | _______  | |
| | |     |  | |
| | |field|  | |
| | |_____|  | |
| |__>_______| |
|    |         |
|    -->Inner  |
|   Horizontally expanding repeating frame
|______________|
```

I would like to center align the label with respect to the field in the inner repeating frame. For example,
If the repeating frame generates 5 fields, the label needs to be right above the 3rd field.
Is this possible using oracle reports or any alternate layouts?. Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I just got this working with a quick mock-up and here is how I did it:

1) Select the "Anchor" tool from the tool palette and anchor the bottom middle "outline square" (I'm not sure what the technical term for those are but the grab-points on an object where you can resize them) from the label object and connect it to the top middle "outline square" of the horizontal repeating frame.

2) [Optional] Click on the anchor line and check the properties to make sure the Child Edge Type is set to "Bottom", the Child Edge Percent is "50", the Parent Edge Type is "Top", and the Parent Edge Percent is "50".

3) Click on the label and set the Keep With Anchoring Object property to "Yes".

4) Make sure your label is centered over the repeating frame in the Paper Layout view. I noticed that if it is off-centered to start with it will be off-centered by the same amount when run. I ended up making the label the same width as the repeating frame it was over and then set both to a Horizontal Elasticity of "Variable".

I ran this with 5 horizontally repeated objects and then I added a 6th to verify it remained centered and both worked.

Hope that helps and that I didn't miss a step. I'll save the mock-up in case it needs further steps or explanation.